# Django: Template não encontrado :(

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Estou criando uma url que vai fazer o update das informações enviadas no form. Eu nunca trabalhei com uma url que puxasse um id, e agora estou recebendo um erro de que o TemplateDoesNotExist e não estou entendo o motivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Não sei muito bem como funciona quando o url possui uma pk, de que forma o django localiza o template na pasta nesse caso e também não sei se o problema é por conta da PK ou  se eu estou cometendo algum outro erro, talvez na views.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Galera, consegui resolver. Só para que caso alguém mais tenha o mesmo problema, quando eu mudei o context para baixo e alterei no return render a url para "contatos/analise.html" a url abriu certinho.